# not responding when use intent in cardview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, drop-down-menu, android-cardview

i have a problem with my code

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var rvRecipes: RecyclerView
private var list: ArrayList<Resep> = arrayListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    rvRecipes = findViewById(R.id.rv_recipes)
    rvRecipes.setHasFixedSize(true)

    list.addAll(DataResep.listData)
    showRecyclerList()
}

private fun showRecyclerList() {
    rvRecipes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val listResep = ListResep(list)
    rvRecipes.adapter = listResep

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    setMode(item.itemId)
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun setMode(selectedMode: Int) {
    when (selectedMode) {
        R.id.action_list -> {
            showRecyclerList()
        }
        R.id.action_menu -> {
            val moveIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, About::class.java)
            startActivity(moveIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

when i press menu about in my action bar, its force close my app

rv_recipes is in activity_main.xml to show cardview and use menu drop list to select about

then logcat:

2020-04-30 14:02:53.795 21454-21454/com.example.submissionproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.submissionproject, PID: 21454
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.submissionproject/com.example.submissionproject.About}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2020)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1679)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4651)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4609)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4970)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4938)
        at com.example.submissionproject.MainActivity.setMode(MainActivity.kt:55)
        at com.example.submissionproject.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:44)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3608)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:384)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:219)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1030)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1198)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3178)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4148)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3890)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:217)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.onTouchEvent(MenuPopupWindow.java:135)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12533)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3026)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2705)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2407)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12774)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5305)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5105)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4779)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4836)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
2020-04-30 14:02:53.801 21454-21454/com.example.submissionproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7356)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7325)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7286)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7462)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:247)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2020-04-30 14:02:53.838 21454-21454/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21454 SIG: 9

Comment: What is the error in logcat

Comment: i have edit my question with log

Comment: Define activity About in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

it say's

```
 Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.submissionproject/com.example.submissionproject.About}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? at
```

Unable to the class and check whether it is defined in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Check if the activity is declared in manifest.xml.
This is common if we directly make activity instead from android studio's "add new activity"